# Warning in the Matchit package ("Glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred") How to deal with that?

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

I'm running a code with around 200.000 observations, where 10.000 were treated and the remaining I'm trying to match using the package MatchIt.

Because of one of these variables, there is a warning message appearing and I don't know if I should just ignore it or not. The message is: Glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

The code that I'm running is similar to the one below:

```
m.out <- matchit(var ~ VAR1 + VAR2 + VAR3 + VAR4 + VAR5, data = mydata, method = "nearest", exact = c("VAR1", "VAR3", "VAR5"))
```

For illustration, let's say that the variable with the issue is the "VAR5". This variable is a character variable with about 200 different texts. So, my question is if this warning is a real problem or if it's just because there are too many options in this variable for the size of my data, and, because of that, it's not possible to find a treatment/control prediction? Anyway, is there something that I can do to not have this warning?

Best,

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I'm still confused. Sorry, I'm a beginner in coding. I saw that they provide some solutions for regression functions, but I don't know how I can implement these solutions in the MatchIt package!

Comment: ,,, nope me either. From a quick glance at the docs, I wonder if there is a way to use a gam distance (i.e.`"GAMlogit"`)  that will allow you to penalise the coefficients using a `gam` argument (`paraPen`) via the `matchit` argument `distance.options`.  But I think this may be best moved to the stats site https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MatchIt` by default uses logistic regression through the `glm` function to estimate propensity scores. This warning means that the logistic regression model has been overfit, with some variables perfectly predicting treatment status. This may indicate a violation of positivity (i.e., your two groups are fundamentally different from each other), but, as you mentioned, it could just be that a relatively unimportant feature has many categories, and some of these perfectly overlap with treatment. There are a few ways to handle this problem; one of them is indeed to drop VAR5, but you can also try to estimate your own propensity scores outside `MatchIt` using a method that doesn't suffer from this problem and then supply those propensity scores to `matchit()` through the `distance` argument.

Two methods come to mind. The first is to use `brglm2`, a package that implements an alternate method of fitting logistic regression models so that fitted probabilities are never 0 or 1. This method is easy to implement because it just uses a slight variation of the `glm` function.

A second is to use a machine learning method that performs regularization (i.e., variable selection) so that only the variables and levels of the factors that are important for the analysis are included. You could use `glmnet` to perform lasso or elastic net logistic regression, you could use `gbm` or `twang` to do generalized boosted modeling, or you could use `SuperLearner` to stack several machine learning methods and take the best predictions from them. You can then supply the predicted values to `matchit()`.